# Replace data in tutorial code with JSON in remote file

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to modify the following code:

```
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', ],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

and read all of the json from a separate file which I added [here](https://securitynews.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/testchartdata.json)

I tried doing this as follows:

```
var requestURL = 'https://securitynews.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/testchartdata.json';
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);
request.responseType = 'json';
request.send();
var chartObject = request.response;
```

but I get an error "cannot read proper type of Null" at the javascript console when I try to use the JSON from the link I provided (chartObject variable).

Comment: https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest

Comment: Your code is not working because your responseType from [testchartdata.json](https://securitynews.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/testchartdata.json) is not a valid JSON. You can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`send` is not synchronous. You try to read `response` before the call is done. You need to supply `XMLHttpRequest` with a callback to be used when you get the response back from *securitynews*.

```js
const requestURL =
  "https://securitynews.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/testchartdata.json";
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", requestURL);
request.send();

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (request.readyState === 4) {
    var chartObject = request.response;
    console.log(chartObject);
  }
};
```